# Viewing a CSV in Python

Tags: python, csv, search, view

How would I go about correcting this code, so that I can view the contents of the CSV?

```
import csv

def csv_to_list("jo.csv", delimiter=','):

    with open("jo.csv", 'r') as csv_con:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_con, delimiter=delimiter)
        return list(reader)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to do but the proper usage of `csv.reader` is:

```
import csv
with open("jo.csv", 'r') as csv_con:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_con, delimiter=delimiter)
    for row in reader:
        # Process rows here
        print(', '.join(row))
```

One of the goals of `csv.reader` is not to load the whole file in the `reader` but to access it row by row.

Comment: Thanks.  But, this seems to bring back 'invalid syntax'

Comment: Could you paste the error message? Maybe it is the `print`. If you use python 3 you need to use `print(', '.join(row))`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\csvprog.py", line 2, in <module>
    with open("jo.csv", 'r') as csv_con:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'jo.csv'

Comment: The above message comes up, which is strange because i definitely have the file 'jo.csv' in my the same folder as my python prog

Comment: Your working directory is probably not the directory of your script. Try this to identify it: `import os; print os.getcwd()` . You probably need an absolute path or to change your current working directory.

Comment: Current working directory has both files in them!  import os;print(os.getcwd()) returns correct drive.  But then the error message appears beneath!

Comment: Please your updated code in your question at top :).